# Python removes zeros when reading a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I am writing a program where it needs to store some numbers.

```
2000
0
1100
1400
75
100
```

But when reading it removes zeros from some of the numbers and does other mystical things.

```
with open('stats.txt') as f:
    money = f.readline(1)
    quantity = f.readline(2)
    min_earnings = f.readline(3)
    max_earnings = f.readline(4)
    min_current_cost = f.readline(5)
    max_current_cost = f.readline(6)
print(money, quantity, min_earnings, max_earnings, min_current_cost, max_current_cost)
```

And he brings out:`2 0 0 0 1100 1400` I tried to use `int()`, google about this problem but I find nothing.

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: What do you think the argument to `f.readline()` means? Hint: It's not the line number.

Comment: If your file is six lines long just do `money, quantity, min_earnings, max_earnings, min_current_cost, max_current_cost = map(int, f)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but your [`f.readline(n)`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_file_readline.asp) isn't quite doing what you think it is. There're a lot of solutions to this (I would use a 2D dictionary if you plan on storing multiple "bank accounts"), but this is a simple approach that might lead you to see one of many solutions.

```py
status = []

with open('stats.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        status.append(i.strip())
    money = status[0]
    quantity = status[1]
    min_earnings = status[2]
    max_earnings = status[3]
    min_current_cost = status[4]
    max_current_cost = status[5]
```

By no means is it optimal, or elegant, but I hope you can see what `i` is more clearly this way when we loop through `readline()`. Let me know if there is any confusion.

Comment: WOW thank you so much for helping me, u'll never be forgotten by me

Answer (score 1):

The number you pass to `readline` is the [number of bytes to read](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/readline.html). You don't need to say which line (number) you want to read, reading a file (almost always) starts at the beginning and once a line is read, the next line is up for reading.

Just remove the numbers from your `readline`s and the code reads and prints whole lines.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldnt it just be easier to put each line into a list and then print the list?

```
lines = []
with open('stats.txt') as f:
    lines.append(f.readline())

print(*lines, sep = ", ")
```

Comment: But then the variables don't have names like `money` and `quantity`, and you'll have to use list indices to access them. Fine for printing, inconvenient for further calculations. Guess it depends on what the code should do.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, i was going to the point of their example doesn't do anything with the variables except print them

Comment: Hopefully it's a [mcve], so it doesn't mean the real life code also just prints them. Or you could just use `cat` and wouldn't have to write a program.  :-)